# third party website scraping without API

Tags: java, web-scraping

I need to scrap [this](http://www.thessaloniki.gr/egov/budget.html) website, according to the choices made on a couple of combo boxes.
The problem is that there is no API and the URL is constant so I can not copy the url to match the criteria.

I managed, using the firefox inspector, to figure out the post command,
[image]
 but when using it in a java program as such:

```
String url = "  https://gaiacrmkea.c-gaia.gr/city_thessaloniki/index.php";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "el-GR,el;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
    String urlParameters = "fyear=2015&esex=0&cdief=Όλες";
    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine+"\n");

    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());
```

doesn't work. It only returns the graphics and the buttons, but no real data.
When I copy the parameters and paste it to firefox, as such
[https://gaiacrmkea.c-gaia.gr/city_thessaloniki/index.php?fyear=2015&esex=0&cdief=Όλες](https://gaiacrmkea.c-gaia.gr/city_thessaloniki/index.php?fyear=2015&esex=0&cdief=%CE%8C%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%82)

I am getting it just right.

any ideas?

Edit:
I would like that to be done automatically every day.

Edit2:
SOLVED!
Based on the code provided by Özhan Düz I added these

```
Select type= document
                .query("#esex")
                .getSelect();
            type.setSelectedIndex(1);
            type.change();

            Select dep =document
                    .query("#cdief")
                    .getSelect();

            dep.setSelectedIndex(1);
            dep.change();
```

in order to get all three comboboxes.
now i only need to do this automatically executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the open souce [ui4j](https://github.com/ui4j/ui4j) web automation library. Download the [ui4j-all](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/ui4j/ui4j-ide/1.1.0/ui4j-ide-1.1.0.jar) jar and use **Java 8** to run the sample.

```
package test;

import java.util.List;

import com.ui4j.api.browser.BrowserEngine;
import com.ui4j.api.browser.BrowserFactory;
import com.ui4j.api.browser.Page;
import com.ui4j.api.dom.Document;
import com.ui4j.api.dom.Element;
import com.ui4j.api.dom.Select;

public class WebScraping {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        BrowserEngine webkit = BrowserFactory.getWebKit();

        // load the page
        Page page = webkit.navigate("https://gaiacrmkea.c-gaia.gr/city_thessaloniki/index.php");
        page.show();

        // get the DOM
        Document document = page.getDocument();

        // find the year combobox
        Select year = document
                        .query("#fyear")
                        .getSelect();

        // select year 2011
        year.setSelectedIndex(0);
        // trigger the change event
        year.change();

        // Small delay before the page load
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        // find the data table
        Element table = document
                            .query("#example")
                            .query("tbody");

        // iterate all rows
        List<Element> rows = table.queryAll("tr");
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
            Element row = rows.get(i);

            // iterate all columns
            List<Element> cells = row.queryAll("td");

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < cells.size(); j++) {
                Element cell = cells.get(j);
                String text = cell.getText();
                builder.append(text).append(" ");
            }

            System.out.println(builder.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: will give that a try asap and get back to you.thanks

Comment: This is a great tip! BUT what i didnt mention was that i need this to be done automatically every day. I didn't really mentioned it on my question because i thought it would be easily adjasted, but with your COOL solution, i need to do it manually. Any other ideas?

Comment: Making custom calls can be tedious when cookies are used to track state, view states are present; etc. Even when mimicking tings perfectly, it can be quite easy to lose something in translation and watch page errors climb. Ui4j, JavaFX, and the QT network use webkit and selenium and Ui4j have both wekit and chromium. Ui4j does not have the memory leak problem of selenium. It would be nice to see its functionality surpass what can be implemented in QTJambi or Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You set parameters seems for GET rather then POST:

> String urlParameters = "fyear=2015&esex=0&cdief=Όλες";

In your setting up for post request you probably need smth. like this (see the 3-d line):

```
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "el-GR,el;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
con.setRequestParameters(<parameters' array>); // "fyear=2015&esex=0&cdief=Όλες" as an array
con.setDoOutput(true);
```

Comment: what is this array? it is not returning any errors as it is